# How to access cookie with domain in an AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, attributes

I have the following AuthorizeAttribute

```
  public class SSOAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var cookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies["testcookie"];
        if (cookie == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("cookie does not exist in attribute");
            cookie = new HttpCookie("testcookie")
            {
                Value = "test",
                Domain = "someotherdomain"
            };
            httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("cookie exists in attribute");
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the following controller (MVC 5.0)

```
  [SSO]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["testcookie"];
        if (cookie == null)
            Debug.WriteLine("cookie does not exist in Index");
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("cookie exists in Index");

        return RedirectToAction("Second");
    }

    public ActionResult Second()
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["testcookie"];
        if (cookie == null)
            Debug.WriteLine("cookie does not exist in Second");
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("cookie exists in Second");

        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

When I run this test application, the output is

> cookie does not exist in attribute
>
> cookie exists in Index
>
> cookie does not exist in attribute
>
> cookie exists in Second

Without the domain, everything works fine. The attribute finds the cookie as expected on the second pass. Once I add the domain however, the attribute returns null when searching for the cookie. It still shows up just fine in the controller. Can someone please explain why this is, and how I can go about seeing this cookie in the attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing the cookie in the attribute is because it's set for a different domain, so the browser is not even sending it with the request. Try running [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) while making the requests; you should see that the cookies you're setting on the other domain are not included in the requests you're making.

The reason you're seeing the cookie in the controller each time despite that is because you're re-setting it each time in the attribute, when it's initially not found, since the attribute runs before the controller is hit. Set the cookie value to something variable, like `DateTime.Now.ToString()`, and print that to Debug to see what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, after continuing to research and think about it, I realized that is what it is. When the cookie is manually created, it shows up. But as soon as the browser initiates the next call, the cookie is not included because of the domain. Thanks for the response.